# Palindromic Wing Primes - Mathematica

Tags: numbers, wolfram-mathematica, primes

definition :
Palindromic Wing Primes (or PWP's for short) are numbers that
are primes, palindromic in base 10, and consisting of one central digit
surrounded by two wings having an equal amount of identical digits and
different from the central one. E.g.

101
99999199999
333333313333333
7777777777772777777777777
11111111111111111111111111111111411111111111111111111111111111111

A number is a palindromic wing prime if it is both a palindromic wing and prime.  Here are the first several palindromic wing primes:
101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 11311, 11411, 33533, 77377, 77477, 77977, 1114111, 1117111, 3331333, 3337333, 7772777, 7774777, 7778777, 111181111, 111191111, 777767777, 77777677777,...

Please i need help with find the right  algorithm or pseudo  code for if a number is palindromic wing
and if someone could help me with guid me to more info about the Palindromic Wing Primes , their history and the last results and maybe help me with "mathematica Programming " that would be amazing

kind regards

Comment: look up `PrimeQ`, `IntegerDigits`

Answer (score 1):

Testing wing palindromes from wing length 1 to 20 using Mathematica.

```
sets = DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[0, 9], 2], {a_, a_} | {0, _}];

grow[n_] := Map[Flatten, {a = ConstantArray[#1, n], #2, a} & @@@ sets]

test[c_] := If[PrimeQ[k = FromDigits@c], AppendTo[output, k]]

run[from_, to_] := Do[test /@ grow[i], {i, from, to}]

output = {};
run[1, 20]
```

> ```
> 101
> 131
> 151
> 181
> 191
> ...
> 111111111111111111131111111111111111111
> 777777777777777777797777777777777777777
> 77777777777777777777977777777777777777777
> ```

Comment: thanks a lot , that's great ,please can you change the above code to make  the iteration as input from user instead of the value 20 ?
Kind Regards

Comment: I've added a function called `run[]`. It doesn't reset the output list so that you don't lose previous results when you rerun with different wing-length ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting definition, first time that I hear about that.

Assuming that you know how to check if a number is palindromic and prime, here is some pseudo and python code

```
isPalindromicWing(N){
    if isPalindromic(N){
        num <- toString(N)
        tam <- length(num)
        if isOdd(tam) and lenght(toSet(num)) = 2{
            middle <- num[ floor(tam/2) ] 
            if 1 = num.count(middle){
                return True
            }
        }
     }
     return False
}

isPWP(N){
    return isPalindromicWing(N) and isPrime(N)
}
```

I use sets to remove repetitions, and as the number can only have 2 different digit with `lenght(toSet(num)) == 2` I check for that, then I take the middle number and check if only there is one of it in the number. The rest I think is self explanatory.

in python that is

```
def isPalindromic(N):
    num = str(N)
    return N == int( num[::-1] )

def isPalindromicWing(n):
    if isPalindromic(n):
        num = str(n)
        tam = len(num)
        if tam % 2 == 1 and len(set(num)) == 2:
            middle = num[tam // 2]
            if 1 == num.count(middle):
                return True 
    return False
```

I don't know about "mathematica Programming", but is you understand this code surely you can do it in that too

Comment: thank you for pseudo and python codes .
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java solution. It prints the first 100 PWP. Certainly prime until #37, probable prime the rest

The source is present in [PWP100.java](https://github.com/matteo65/mzpp19/blob/main/src/PWP100.java)

```
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class PWP100 {
        
    static final int MAX_LENGTH = 169; // Increase to print more PWP

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 1;
        char[] digits = {'1', '3', '7', '9'};
        for(int len = 1; len < MAX_LENGTH; len++) {
            for(char c : digits) {
                
                String num = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    num += c;
                
                for(char pivot = '0'; pivot <= '9'; pivot++) {
                    if(pivot != c) {
                        String palindromeWing = num + pivot + num;
                        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(palindromeWing);
                        if(bi.isProbablePrime(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                            System.out.println(counter++ + " " + palindromeWing);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```